# Difference between Named and BIND

Tags: nameserver, bind

Can someone explain to me what the exact difference is between named and BIND?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nothing :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND

named is just an alias of BIND.

Comment: Yup. "nameD" fits the standard daemon naming conventions for Unix, wherein services are named "service"+"d" (httpd, smbd, dhcpd, ftpd, sshd, etcd). I supposed bindd was either conflicting with some other bin+d daemon, or not considered "user-friendly" enough...Oh jesus, just hurt myself a little saying that.

Answer (score 15):

Though they are often used synonymously, *BIND* is the whole package.  *named* is one of the parts of that package (but only one part.)

In addition to the nameserver daemon (named), ISC BIND contains a number of utilities (e.g. dig, host, named-checkconf, named-compilezone, dnssec-signzone, etc..) and libraries (e.g. libbind)

Answer (score 9):

BIND stands for Berkeley Internet Name Domain, is the most commonly used Domain Name System (DNS) server on the Internet.

Named is the daemon used by BIND.